# jQuery show hidden hotspot on click?

Tags: jquery, show-hide

I have a series of DIVs, each with an image of an X:

`<div class="hotspot" id="hs1" class="hotspot"><img src="images/xmark.png" alt="x"></div>`

What I want to do is start out with them hidden but still clickable, and then onclick show the image inside.

If I use

```
<div class="hotspot" id="hs1" class="hotspot">
    <img class="x" src="images/xmark.png" alt="x">
</div>

.hotpsot img { visibility: hidden;}
```

and then

```
$('#hs1').click(function(){
        $(this).find(img).show();
});
```

The div does get the click, but the image is not shown.

I have also tried display:none, and children()

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#hs1').click(function(){
    $(this).find('img').show();
});
```

Just missing the quotes around the `img` selector.

Also, a suggestion. Please remove the double `class` attribute in your HTML markup below:

```
<div class="hotspot" id="hs1" class="hotspot">
    <img class="x" src="images/xmark.png" alt="x">
</div>
```

Just one `class` attribute is enough:

```
<div class="hotspot" id="hs1">
   <img class="x" src="images/xmark.png" alt="x">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Enclose `img` in quotes to get the element using tag selector other wise `img` would be assumed as variable. You are not properly closing img tag `/` is missing.

The image is hidden by `visibility:hidden` but show uses display property not `visibility` use `display:none` in `css` which is used by show method.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xztqD/1/)**

```
$('#hs1').click(function(){
    $(this).find('img').show();
});
```